# What is the idiomatic way of extracting two segment values from uri path in akka-http via PathMatchers?

Tags: scala, akka-http

I try to build an akka-http route to extract two values from the endpoint `api/<value1>/<value2>` so that I have convenient access to domain objects `Foo(<value1>)` and `Bar(<value2>)`. The domain looks as follows:

```
  final case class Foo(foo: String)

  object Foo {
    def apply(value: String): Try[Foo] = Try {
      if (value.length == 3)
        new Foo(value)
      else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Foo value $value invalid.")
    }
  }

  final case class Bar(bar: String)

  object Bar {
    def apply(value: String): Try[Bar] = Try {
      if (value.length == 4)
        new Bar(value)
      else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Bar value $value invalid.")
    }
  }
```

As I couldn't find any good practice example, so far I have come up with:

```
  val fooBarPM: PathMatcher1[Option[(Foo, Bar)]] =
    Segments.map(as => Foo.apply(as.head).toOption.flatMap(foo => Bar.apply(as(1)).toOption.map(bar => (foo, bar) )))

  private def fooBarPath(pm: PathMatcher1[Option[(Foo, Bar)]])
                        (handler: (Foo, Bar) => Route) = path(pm) {
      case None => complete("Invalid foo/bar.")
      case Some((a, b)) => handler(a, b)
    }
  
  val route2: Route =
    pathPrefix("api") {
      fooBarPath(fooBarPM) { (foo, bar) =>
        complete(s"Foo Bar ok: $foo, $bar")
      }
    }
```

This seems to work as expected for most of valid and invalid cases except for `api/aaa` for which `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown. I suspect it is an exception context somehow badly passed over but also wonder if there is some better or idiomatic approach.

Comment: Have you tried something like https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/path-matchers.html ? where you would use `Segment.?` for optional path and validation in the following function

Answer (score 0):

The following code doesn't have the problem of `IndexOutOfBoundsException` caused by `as(1)`

```scala
case class Foo(foo: String)
case class Bar(bar: String)

val fooBarPath: Directive[(Foo, Bar)] = pathPrefix(Segment / Segment).tflatMap {
  case (foo, bar) if foo.length == 3 && bar.length == 4 => tprovide(Foo(foo), Bar(bar))
  case _                                                => reject.toDirective[(Foo, Bar)]
}

val route: Route = pathPrefix("api") {
  fooBarPath { case (foo, bar) =>
    complete(s"Got $foo and $bar")
  }
}
```

Use `tflatMap` to convert to correct value, `(Foo, Bar)`, or `reject` the directive of the incoming request does not fit the criteria.

You could also use a combination of `tfilter`/`tmap` to isolate the filtering/rejection logic from mapping logic.